# Sensors report in web using docker

Tags: linux, docker, monitoring, sensors

I would like to monitor the sensors on my microserver (temperature, fan) and have access to some webpage with the stats eg http://localhost:xxxx. So, the report should indicate in fact the output of `watch -n2 sensors`

First thought is to use lm-sensors in docker. Would you help to understand how to create the report service and dockerise it? Maybe there some other better simple local solutions?

Comment: Containers are usually prevented from directly accessing hardware devices.  This service might be simpler to develop and run without Docker.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I see your point. By now I found that monitorix covers my needs, though it provides a lot of exhaustive information.

Comment: Ok, if not in docker. How to create small web app to show the regularly updated data from lm-sensors, eg by executing the above mentioned command watch sensors watch -n 1 -d sensors?